# Styling the clicked placeholder in CSS

Tags: html, css, placeholder

When styling a placeholder, we use ::-webkit-input-placeholder, but what if we want to style a placeholder of a clicked input text field?
For an example, http://www.bbc.com/news/uk
the color of placeholder of the search box on the right top in the website is dark gray, but when you click in the search box, the color turns into light gray. Can I know how was that done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `:focus` and `::-webkit-input-placeholder` to achieve this. Here is the working [**demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/rw03ve3y/2/)

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" placeholder="My Placeholder" id="myInput">
```

**CSS**

```
#myInput:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder { 
     color: red;
}
```